# Is there an automated way to run something between each methods in a testcase?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

I am running a few unit-tests using the TestClient supplied with Django that makes it easy to have the same database in each test method. However in some of my tests I connect to a external webservice that I want to reset between each of the test method.

I can do this resetting by simply calling an url but I want the testrunner to do this automaticly between each of the test methods.

Is there a simple way to do this without haing to call the reset function the first thing in every test method?

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing is what the `setUp()` method is for.

Answer (score 0):

> setUp() - called immediately before calling the test method
>
> tearDown() - called immediately after the test method has been called and the result recorded

source: http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html